# nltk works in jupyter, but not sublime text 3

Tags: python, nltk, sublimetext3, jupyter

I have nltk installed and no problem when I 'import nltk' in Jupyter, but when I 'import nltk in Sublime Text 3, it gave me below error:

```
''''''''''''
File "C:\Users\xxxxx343\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am using python 2.7, and have checked sublime text is using the same python to build system as Jupyter.

Comment: Try pip installing it again. Are you using windows or linux?

Comment: `conda activate`

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami I cannot do pip install, my company block anaconda site, all installation has to be manually, i.e easy_install downloaded package :-( :-( :-(